# How to remove part of a model and create a handle?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender so sorry if I posted it in the wrong place or someone else has already answered this.

What i am trying to make is a bleach bottle something like this:

[image]

Right now i currently have a basic shape for the bottle:
[image]
but i want to know how i can remove a curve from the model and put in a curved handle.

Comment: Yes, as lemon mentioned bellow, you probably started in the wrongfoot. It will be hard to achieve that through direct vertex manipulation, you need a lower poly version of your mesh, add a *Subsurf* modifier and work from there as illustrated bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but I propose this approach :

[image]

- Upper left, the base shape (only extruded cube)
- Lower left, the same with a subsurf modifier
- Upper right, vertices adjustment in order to fit the shape
- Lower right, the same with subsurf

[image]

**Edit** for some explanations as Thefundude said to be new to Blender :

The main idea is to start from a basic shape which as the topology of the bottle. So mainly here, has a hole below the handle and is opened at the top.

The very basic first shape is here for that (defining the topology), but also, as it is very basic (few vertices), its vertices can be used as handles to reshape this starting mesh to the wanted shape.

The subsurface modifier is used to round the shape.

Here is how to set it up :

- Select your starting mesh
- Go to the modifier panel and select the *subsurface* modifier
- Give it one or two subdivisions

[image]

Now the first part to enhance will probably be the handle. We want it curve. We will use the spin tool for that.

- Remove the non curve part
- Place your cursor at a pivot point (the spin uses the cursor as pivot). Select the location and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and '*cursor to selected*'
- Select the vertices to spin
- Place the view in the spin axis. Here front view so <kbd>NumPad1</kbd>
- Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to invoke the spin tool
- Change the amount of steps to an amount which more or less preserves the proportionalities of the whole model (the same precision everywhere, for now)
- Finally, as the spin has created vertices which overlaps already created vertices (these on the bottom right here), select them (or all) and remove doubles.

[image]

After that, this is mainly tuning and adjusting matter.

For instance you can scale the handle :

[image]

Or add some more geometry to refine the shape :

[image]

Or want to add more edge loops, in particular to flatten the base (I used here the '*inset tool*' which is invoked by <kbd>I</kbd> (then adjust moving the mouse) :

[image]

Step by step (but starting from an appropriated topology, adding few vertices as you want to master the shape easily) you can refine your shape without arriving to the complex situation of your question.

Cheers !

[image]